# Ag-grid - button causing page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I've got a component that uses ag-grid. The component is eventually rendered inside a form element on another page. (I don't have any control over that situation.) In the grid I have a filter button on each column like this...

[image]

The red circle shows the button. The problem occurs when the user clicks on the button the page that the component is embedded in reload because the default action for a button inside the form is to submit it. I'd like to do a simple event.preventDefault() to keep that behavior from happening but I cannot figure out where to do this with ag-grid.

Comment: This same issue shows up on the pagination buttons as well (see https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2138).  It looks like it's in the backlog for the next release (AG-1073 at https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/) but it's not clear whether they'll fix the same issue with the floating filter button.